# How to create grapple effect in java swing?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a 2D platformer using java swing, working on making a grappling hook. I'm not sure how to calculate its horizontal or vertical acceleration/how to move along the ellipse. Does anybody have any suggestions?

I was thinking about using an ellipse with the contact point as one of the foci and the character as one of the edge points of the ellipse, but this causes the movement to be inaccurate and jerky.

Comment: What is a "grapple effect"?

Comment: This is more of a math question and has nothing to do with Swing per se

Comment: Try adding more tags to your question, rather than just `java`, I'm sure you'll get more responses.